# Why does my application go into 'break mode' when an exception should be thrown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code in a client Console app, trying to get a JWT from my Web API server:

```
private static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string userName, string password)
{
    var login = new { username = "mario", password = "secret" };
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var resp = await _client.PostAsync("api/Token", content);
    var json = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var parsedObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    return parsedObject["token"].ToString();
}
```

I am now getting an error page back HTML in the response, not the expected json, and when the `parsedObject = JObject.Parse(json);` line is hit with invalid json, instead of an exception being thrown, I get a page in VS telling me my application is in 'break mode', whatever that means. There is an option to continue, but when I click it, my client app just keeps on running as if nothing happened.

Comment: Check the exception settings, you should have set it to stop at any exception. check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx. Is the client waiting for the async task to end? that can explain why it is not affected.

Comment: How do you call this method?

Comment: @Mahdi `var token = await GetTokenAsync("...", "...");`

Comment: @ProfK In your console app I meant. I assume there is a main somewhere in which you call this method, right?

Comment: @Mahdi In the console app I call that method just like I showed, inside my `Main` method..NET Core 2 allows an async Main method.